# Send multiple images in email using mail()

Tags: php, email

I stored the images in url format in database.now i want to send mail with multiple images using mail() in php

```
$sql11 = "SELECT `photo_id`, `project_id`, `map_id`, `map_flag`, `user_id`, `photo_path`, `pdf_path`, `created_at`, `modified_at` FROM `photos` WHERE map_flag='Task' and map_id='$task_id'";
$rl    = $conn->query($sql11);
while ($res11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rl)) {
    $array[] = [$res11['photo_path']];
}
$str     = implode(',', $array);
$message = $message_content . "\n" . "\n" . "\n" . $message1 . "\n" . $message2 . "\n" . $message3 . "\n" . $message4 . "\n" . $message5 . "\n" . $message6 . "\n" . $array . "\n" . $message8 . "\n";
$from    = "123@test.com";
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$result  = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: replace your `$array` with `$str` in `$message` creation

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to tell the email app that this is html. This can be done by adding the line

```
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
```

Next, what is `photo_path`? Does it also include the full url or a relative url? You need to set the full url i.e. `http://example.com/{$res11['photo_path']}`

Comment: I tried that above code total alignment are changed..image also doesn't view

Comment: You need to put the images within an HTML img element i.e. <img src='...'>

Comment: thanks. now I got a image in mail.while using while() loop i got only first image remaining images are not shown

Comment: $sql11="SELECT `photo_id`, `project_id`, `map_id`, `map_flag`, `user_id`, `photo_path` FROM `photos` WHERE map_flag='Task' and map_id='$task_id'";
$rl=$conn->query($sql11);
while($res11 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($rl))
{
 $message7="<img src='$res11[photo_path]' style='width:250px;height:250px;'>";
}
$message=$message_content."\n"."\n"."\n".$message1."\n".$message2."\n".$message3."\n".$message4."\n".$message5."\n".$message6."\n".$message7."\n".$message8."\n";
$from="123@test.com";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from. "\r\n";
$result=mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);